# General formula of $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a^ib+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, products

Is there any general formula of the following product?. Thank you in advance.
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a^ib+1)$$

Comment: Have you tried developping this expression for low values of n?

Comment: Does your product iterate over $i$? I.e. should the expression under the product be "$i = 0$"? Also, unlike your tag suggests, this is not an infinite product.

Answer (score 3):

check out the q-Pochhammer-symbol, it might be what you're looking for. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You're very welcome. :)